# json.net not converting xml node to array

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

I am converting an XML document to JSON.

I have a node that could be multiple nodes.

The [Json.Net documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm) says to force the serialization of the node into an array I should add the `json:array=true` attribute.

On my root node I add the add the `json` namespace:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "json", null, "http://james.newtonking.com/json");
```

then on the element I need to be an array I add the `json:array=true` attribute:

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("Array", "http://james.newtonking.com/json", "true");
```

The XML looks as expected:

```
<result xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/json">
<object json:Array="true">
```

but the JSON looks like this:

```
"result": {
"@xmlns:json": "http://james.newtonking.com/json",
  "object": {
    "@json:Array": "true",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You've got the XML namespace wrong.  It should be:

```
http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json
```

not

```
http://james.newtonking.com/json
```

Working demo with correct namespace:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

        string xmlns = "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json";

        writer.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("result");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "json", null, xmlns);
        writer.WriteStartElement("object");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Array", xmlns, "true");
        writer.WriteStartElement("foo");
        writer.WriteString("bar");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();

        string xml = sb.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(xml);

        Console.WriteLine();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, 
                                          Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<result xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json">
  <object json:Array="true">
    <foo>bar</foo>
  </object>
</result>

{
  "?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "utf-16"
  },
  "result": {
    "object": [
      {
        "foo": "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```